# Compare two dynamic Datatable & highlight differences between the two

Tags: c#

Requirement:

I have a master table (Eg: Cities).This table is used as a reference table in other transaction tables in the application.This table can undergo following changes
1- Add new row to this table
2- Add new column to the table
3- Modify existing values
4- Delete existing values

Now because this is a used as a reference table in other tranactions tables,the changes cannot be reflected in the main table & so there is a second pair of eyes check(SPOE) involved.For this, when the table undergoes any of the above changes,I create  another table in the database that will act as a temporary table & save it. SPOE check screen should be such that he/she can easily identify the differences between the two table.If there are new rows or columns added,changes in existing values, it should be highlighed as given in the attachment.

**Note: This logic is to be applied for any master table.No columns are known in advanced.Passing table name should highlight the differences between main table & temporary table.**

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,

Farhin

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. It is unclear what you are asking. Also include the source code you have (and tried) and the table structure you are using. Also see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help be feel this might be a better task to be done in SQL.  We need more information about what platform you are working with (WPF? Web app MVC etc).

I assumed you are using data tables.  If so, you can use `Merge` to combine the 2 tables and use the `id` field with some logic to see if the data was modified. None of the solutions provided below is very elegant. I hope someone else can come up with a better solution.

```
 DataTable datatable1 = GetDataTableOne();//Original Table that was modified

            DataTable datatable2 = GetDataTableTwo();

            datatable1.Merge(datatable2);
```

Alternatively, if you need to identify new columns, you can use LINQ to perform a left join followed by a check to see if new column was created.

```
 var leftJoinDataRows = (from dt1 in datatable1.AsEnumerable()
                                join dt2 in datatable2.AsEnumerable() on dt1.Field<int>("id") equals dt2.Field<int>("id") into leftouter
                                from dt2 in leftouter.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                select dt1).ToList();

        var dataTable2Columns = datatable2.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                             .Select(x => x.ColumnName)
                             .ToArray();
        var newColumns = datatable1.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                            .Where(x => !dataTable2Columns.Contains(x.ColumnName))
                             .Select(x => x.ColumnName)
                            .ToArray();

        foreach (var dr in leftJoinDataRows)
        {
            foreach (var column in newColumns)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dr[column]);
            }
        }
```

**Data Tables**

```
 private static DataTable GetDataTableTwo()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("id", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
        dt.Columns.Add("name", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));

        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        row["id"] = "1";
        row["name"] = "Farhin";
        dt.Rows.Add(row);

        row = dt.NewRow();
        row["id"] = "2";
        row["name"] = "salli";
        dt.Rows.Add(row);

        return dt;
    }
    private static DataTable GetDataTableOne()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("id", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
        dt.Columns.Add("name", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("city", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        row["id"] = "1";
        row["name"] = "Farhin";
        row["city"] = "new city row 1";
        dt.Rows.Add(row);

        row = dt.NewRow();
        row["id"] = "2";
        row["name"] = "salli";
        row["city"] = "new city row 2";
        dt.Rows.Add(row);

        row = dt.NewRow();
        row["id"] = "3";
        row["name"] = "John";
        row["city"] = "new city row 3";
        dt.Rows.Add(row);

        return dt;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go in a way that you have a set of tables called something like "WaitForApproval".

In this table, you would store any operation requested on the Master table.

So when your SPOE checks for changes, they are available at once.

The table would be something like this :

- RequestID -> Unique ID, Primary Key
- MasterTableName -> would contain the name of the master table that changes are requested for.
- RequestedChange -> would store the requested change type (1, 2, 3 or 4)

Then for each change type you would have a table containing the data (example for change 1) :
Table name : RequestNewRow

- ID -> PK, UniqueID
- RequestID -> Foreign Key for primary table
- ColumnName -> name of the column in the Master table
- ColumnValue -> Value to be inserted

So for each row add you would have one row in "RequestNewRow" per column and one row in "WaitForApproval"

The general idea is that the row are not inserted as long as they have not been approved...
You then have to create the required Stored Procedure in order to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Salli for your answer.Although I had to tweak the solution for the newly added records. To answer your question on the platform I am using; ASP.NET MVC.
I had to take this approach on c# & javascript as the requirement is to highligh the differences between the two tables created.
Below is the final implementation that I had ended up with:
C#

```
    public SPOEReview GetFileDetailsForSPOEReview(int fileUploadId)
    {         
    var spoeFileToReview.SubmittedTemplate = GetTemplateDetails(spoeFileToReview.ApprovalTemplateName, spoeFileToReview.Year);

        if (spoeFileToReview.SubmittedTemplate.Rows.Count > 0 && spoeFileToReview.ExistingTemplate.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            List<DataRow> lstNewRows = spoeFileToReview.SubmittedTemplate.AsEnumerable().Except(
                    spoeFileToReview.ExistingTemplate.AsEnumerable(),
                                              DataRowComparer.Default).ToList();
            var lstRowsExcludingNew = spoeFileToReview.SubmittedTemplate.AsEnumerable().Except(
                          lstNewRows.AsEnumerable(),
                                                    DataRowComparer.Default).ToList();

            // Existing table:
            if (lstRowsExcludingNew != null && lstRowsExcludingNew.Count > 0)
            {
                DataTable dtFinalForExistingTemplates = lstRowsExcludingNew.CopyToDataTable();
                spoeFileToReview.ExistingTemplate = dtFinalForExistingTemplates;
            }

            // Submitted table:
            if (lstNewRows != null && lstNewRows.Count > 0)
            {
                List<DataRow> rowCollection = lstRowsExcludingNew;
                rowCollection.AddRange(lstNewRows);
                DataTable dtFinalForSubmittedTemplates = rowCollection.CopyToDataTable();
                spoeFileToReview.SubmittedTemplate = dtFinalForSubmittedTemplates;
            }

            //This is to get the additional columns of the submitted table if any
            var submittedTemplatesWithAdditionalColumns = spoeFileToReview.ExistingTemplate.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                        .Select(x => x.ColumnName)
                        .ToArray();
            spoeFileToReview.AdditionalColumns = spoeFileToReview.SubmittedTemplate.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                                .Where(x => !submittedTemplatesWithAdditionalColumns.Contains(x.ColumnName))
                                 .Select(x => x.ColumnName)
                                .ToList();
        }

        return spoeFileToReview;
    }
```

Javascript:

```html
function CompareAndHighlightRowsAndColumns() {
    var num = 0;
    var oldValue;
 //Submitted table
    var rowsNewTable= $('#NewTable tbody >tr');
    var columns;
 //Existing table
    var rowsOldTable = $('#OldTable tbody >tr');


    var columns1;
    for (var i = 0; i < rowsNewTable.length; i++) {
        columns = $(rowsNewTable[i]).find('td');
        for (var j = 0; j < columns.length; j++) {

            for (var k = 0; k < rowsOldTable.length; k++) {
                if (i == k) {
                    columns1 = $(rowsOldTable[k]).find('td');
                    for (var r = 0; r < columns1.length; r++) {

                        if (j == r && $(columns[j]).html() != $(columns1[r]).html()) {
                            columns[j].style.background = "PaleGreen";
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
 
    //Change for newly added rows
    if ((rowsNewTable.length != undefined && rowsNewTable.length > 0) && (rowsOldTable.length != undefined && rowsOldTable.length > 0)) {
        var count = rowsNewTable.length - rowsOldTable.length;
        for (var i = rowsNewTable.length - 1; count > 0; i--) {
            cols = $(rowsNewTable[i]).find('td');
            for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
                cols[j].style.background = "PaleGreen";
            }
            count--;
        }

        //Change for Newly added column
        if ((columns.length != undefined && columns.length > 0) && (columns1.length != undefined && columns1.length > 0)) {
            if (columns.length > columns1.length) {
                var countOfColumns = parseInt(columns.length - columns1.length);
                if (countOfColumns > 0) {
                    for (var i = 1; i <= countOfColumns; i++) {                        
                        $('#NewTable tr').find('th:nth-last-child('+i+'), td:nth-last-child('+i+')').css('background', 'PaleGreen');

                    }

                }
 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Final Result with differences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtdIi.png)

Comment: Ahh, you did find a more elegant solution.  This should be the answer!